# Access environment variable in macOS from python

Tags: python, bash, macos, environment-variables, zshrc

I had no .bash_profile file so I created one and the only line in it is this:

```
YOUTUBE_API=someRandomString
```

In my .zshrc file the first line is this:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

And from the command line I can run this:

```
echo $YOUTUBE_API
```

Which gives me a correct output (my API key).

But when I try to do it in Python it returns *None*:

```
import os
print(os.environ.get('YOUTUBE_API'))
```

I'm running python version 3.9.4. Any idea why, and how I may fix it?

Thank you

Comment: I don't know how to make this work, but my advice is don't rely on environment variables in programs, since it creates invisible dependencies. My advice is to get the value from the command line, or hard code it, or put it in a program-specific initialization file, or something like that.

Comment: I disagree strongly.  Environment variables are great for configuration options that vary per system.  They are a well-established configuration technique.

Comment: @calvinhus : `YOUTUBE_API` is not an environment variable. `echo` won't reveal this. You would have to use something like `printenv YOUTUBE_API`, or - in case `printenv` is not available -, `env|grep -xF YOUTUBE_API`.

Answer (score 0):

It only depends on where you run your code from:

- if the process the code runs in has the variable set, it shouldn't be `None`
- if you run the code inside another process, you'll get `None`

**Explanation:**

Each process ID gets it's own environment, stored in `/proc/<pid>/environ` file, where its local non-exported variables get stored. this path gets deleted as soon as the process stops.

The only way to make this work is to either export the variable in the shell, before launch the program, or run `YOUTUBE_API=someRandomString python <your python file>`

Comment: Almost.  It doesn't depend on a new shell, it depends on a new process.

Comment: agreed, it wasn't clear enough, fixed it.

Comment: Well, that's really no better.  Shell is irrelevant.  He's running Python within the same shell, and the variable isn't available, because that's a new process, but not a new shell.

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
export YOUTUBE_API=someRandomString
```

Otherwise, the variable is available to the local shell, but not to any subprocesses.

Comment: I am able to access the variable in different terminals but not inside python. I get the below error. Any lead please.

```>>> import os
>>> os.environ['SECRET_KEY']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/os.py", line 679, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'SECRET_KEY'
```

Comment: You should create a different question instead of resurrecting a 3-year-old thread.  There are too many details we need.